# How to assign the same value to all table cells in a column in a table in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I tried

```
myTable.MyField{:}='AAA'

myTable.MyField(:)='AAA'

myTable.MyField{:}={'AAA'}

myTable.MyField{:}=deal('AAA')
```

but all failed.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB requires:

> To assign to or create a variable in a table, the number of rows must match the height of the table.

So it would be:

```
myTable.MyField = repmat('AAA', length(myTable.MyField), 1);
```

or if you know the column number of `MyField`, you can do:

```
myTable(:,colnum) = {'AAA'};  %where colnum is the column number
```

or otherwise if you don't know the column number, you can directly use the column name as well:

```
myTable(:,'MyField') = {'AAA'};
```